# How to protect activity layout from changing on different android versions?

Tags: android

I designed a calculator on android if I run it on version 4 then all the components are well arranged but when I run on lower version like 2.3 then the arrangement gets changed.

So How to make arrangement of components unchanged in different android versions ?

Comment: can you please post the difference and the layout.xml with this question

Comment: Share the screen shots. Android have various drawable and layout folders to manage different screen resolutions. Have you used widgets with default implementations or your have customized Button and EditText

Answer (score 0):

```
 find the version on which your app is launched. this can be done by using this

  androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
  Find the height of screen using this.

  DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  heightDpi = (int) (metrics.heightPixels);

 now custom your height and width...
if (androidOS.compareToIgnoreCase("4") < 0
|| heightDpi < 500) {
check.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(40, 33));
check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewselecter);
```

}

```
this is how i used and it worked.
Hope this helps you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your layout in such a way that you should make only one time and not to change it again again for that you should use gravity :center,centerhorizontal,centervertical etc according to your need. If anything want to display on top use allignParentTop true and for bottom alignParentBottomTrue.
You can setMargin also but should be consious enough whether to use or not as it may change for different devices.
If you follow this precautions then your layout should be a perfect layout which run on any device.